# I am beginner and want to ask how to extract data from following type of code using beautiful soup:

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to get the text of `class ="description_span"` ,this class is inside `id="Options"`

```
<p id="Options">
   <label class="description_label"> Options : </label> 
   <span class="description_span"> Climatisation ,  ABS ,  Radar de recul ,  Direction assisstée ,  
   Retroviseurs électriques ,  Phares antibrouillard ,  Alarme ,  Jantes Alliage ,  Feux du jour ,  Vitres 
   éléctriques 
   </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<p id="Options">
   <label class="description_label"> Options : </label> 
   <span class="description_span"> Climatisation ,  ABS ,  Radar de recul ,  Direction assisstée ,  
   Retroviseurs électriques ,  Phares antibrouillard ,  Alarme ,  Jantes Alliage ,  Feux du jour ,  Vitres 
   éléctriques 
   </span>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')

print(soup.find("span", {"class" : "description_span"}).text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the text in the span:

```py
span = soup.find("p", id="Options").find("span", class_="description_span")
print(span.text)
```